# Opening a specific file with Python but an error occurred

Tags: python

I am currently trying to make my discord.py bot opening the specific file: `{guild.id}_config.yaml`, here is my following code:

```py
        for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            if guild.get_member(before.id) is None:
                continue
            else:
                def get_channel_id():
                    with open(f'configuration/{guild.id}_config.yaml', 'r') as id_accessor:
                        ID = yaml.safe_load(id_accessor)

                        id_string: discord.TextChannel = guild.get_channel(ID['plugins']['logging']['type']['member_log']['channel'])

                    return id_string

                MemberLoggingChannel = get_channel_id()

                if before.avatar != after.avatar:
                    AvatarEmbed = discord.Embed(title=f":pencil: {before.name} Changed His/Her Avatar", colour=0xa6f7ff)
                    AvatarEmbed.set_thumbnail(url=after.avatar_url)

                    await MemberLoggingChannel.send(embed=AvatarEmbed)
                elif before.name != after.name:
                    NameEmbed = discord.Embed(title=f":pencil: {after.name} Changed His/Her Username", colour=0xa6f7ff)
                    NameEmbed.add_field(name="Before", value=f"{before.name}", inline=True)
                    NameEmbed.add_field(name="After", value=f"{after.name}", inline=False)

                    await MemberLoggingChannel.send(embed=NameEmbed)
                elif before.discriminator != after.discriminator:
                    DiscriminatorEmbed = discord.Embed(title=f":pencil: {after.name} Changed His/Her Username", colour=0xa6f7ff)
                    DiscriminatorEmbed.add_field(name="Before", value=f"{before.discriminator}", inline=True)
                    DiscriminatorEmbed.add_field(name="After", value=f"{after.discriminator}", inline=False)

                    await MemberLoggingChannel.send(embed=DiscriminatorEmbed)
```

But for some reason the guild id isn't in the connected guilds of my bot. Here is the list of connected guild IDs:

- 631100984176672768
- 650736030319771674
- 613660252545613834

And the error looks like so:

```
Ignoring exception in on_user_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "whatever file path", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "whatever file path", line 111, in on_user_update
    MemberLoggingChannel = get_channel_id()
  File "whatever file path", line 104, in get_channel_id
    with open(f'configuration/{guild.id}_config.yaml', 'r') as id_accessor:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'configuration/613660252545613834_config.yaml'
```

How can I fix the problem, and what am I wrong here?

Comment: as error tells: No such file or directory: 'configuration/613660252545613834_config.yaml' - pay attention - its relative path - check from where do you run script if such path exists

Comment: could you give us detailed information about your folder structure?

Comment: ah I made a typo on the path, sorry